# State Space model of a differential eqn. for use in Least Squares

Tags: state-space

The code in [this page](http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~johnc/second_ed/chapter1/example1_2.m) solves the Least Squares problem for the following dynamic model:

$\dot{y}=ay+bu$

where $a$ and $b$ are constants, $u$ is an input. The code is as follow:

```
t=[0:0.1:10];
m=length(t);
y=zeros(m,1);
a=-1;b=1;c=1;d=0;u=[100;zeros(m-1,1)]; % u: impulse with magnitude of 100
[ad,bd]=c2d(a,b,0.1);
y=dlsim(ad,bd,c,d,u);
ym=y+0.08*randn(m,1); %adding Gaussian noise

w=inv(0.08^2);
h=[ym(1:m-1) u(1:m-1)];
xe=inv(h'*w*h)*h'*w*ym(2:m)

ye=dlsim(xe(1),xe(2),c,d,u);
```

What's is not clear to me is why $a=-1$ and $b=1$. The model as given does not specify a value for either of $a$ and $b$. ($c=1$ and $d=0$ are fine, however).